# model update failed with factors in R

Tags: r, model, linear-regression

I wrote a function to reduce a multi-linear model. Each iteration the term with the highest alpha is left out. However, the update does not work with mixed models lm(y~factor+num*num). If the term is a factor, it does not cancel out. Any idea how to adjust the "paste" in case "terms[ind]" is a factor-term?

```
reduce_model_by_p<-function(model){
  while(T){
    c = summary(model)$coefficients
    terms <- names(c[,4])
    print(length(terms))
    max_ = max(c[-1,4])
    ind =  which(c[,4]==max_)
    print(length(max_))
    if(max_>0.05){
      formul <- as.formula(paste(".~.-",terms[ind]))
      model  <- update(model, formul)
    }else{
      return(model)
    }
  }  
}
```

Thx

Answer (score 0):

ok, single factor-levels can not be canceled out.. so here is my solution:

```
reduce_model_by_p<-function(model, factor_names = NULL){
  while(T){
    c = summary(model)$coefficients
    terms <- names(c[,4])
    print(length(terms))
    if(!is.null(factor_names)){
      max_ = max(c[-c(1,which(`dim<-`(grepl(factor_names, terms), dim(terms)), arr.ind=TRUE)),4])
    }else{
      max_ = max(c[-1,4])  
    }
    ind =  which(c[,4]==max_)
    print(length(max_))
    if(max_>0.05){
      formul <- as.formula(paste(".~.-",terms[ind]))
      model  <- update(model, formul)
    }else{
      return(model)
    }
  }  
}
```